# Vue JS no funciona como librería en Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

Tengo una aplicación que estoy desarrollando en Django y quiero usar Vue JS como librería mas no como framework; descargué la librería y la importo pero no me funciona ni siquiera el ejemplo de vue.

**Base.html** *Acá está importada la librería de vue*

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'core/assets/images/favicon.png' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'core/dist/css/style.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
{% block css %}{% endblock %}
</head>

<body class="skin-default fixed-layout">
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="loader__figure"></div>
            <p class="loader__label">Unidades Tecnológicas de Santander</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Main wrapper - style you can find in pages.scss -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Topbar header - style you can find in pages.scss -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <header class="topbar">
            <nav class="navbar top-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- Logo -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'core:index' %}">
                        <!-- Logo icon --><b>
                            <!--You can put here icon as well // <i class="wi wi-sunset"></i> //-->
                            <!-- Dark Logo icon -->
                            <img src="{% static 'core/assets/images/logo-icon.png' %}" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
                            <!-- Light Logo icon -->
                            <img src="{% static 'core/assets/images/logo-light-icon.png' %}" alt="homepage" class="light-logo" />
                        </b>
                        <!--End Logo icon -->
                        <!-- Logo text --><span>
                        <!-- dark Logo text -->
                        <img src="{% static 'core/assets/images/logo-text.png' %}" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
                        <!-- Light Logo text -->    
                        <img src="{% static 'core/assets/images/logo-light-text.png' %}" class="light-logo" alt="homepage" /></span> </a>
                </div>
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- End Logo -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <div class="navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <!-- toggle and nav items -->
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <!-- This is  -->
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link nav-toggler d-block d-md-none waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-menu"></i></a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link sidebartoggler d-none d-lg-block d-md-block waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a> </li>
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <!-- Search -->
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    </ul>
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <!-- User profile and search -->
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav my-lg-0">
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <!-- User Profile -->
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown u-pro">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-dark profile-pic" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="{% static 'core/assets/images/users/1.jpg' %}" alt="user" class=""> <span class="hidden-md-down">Mark &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span> </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right animated flipInY">
                                <!-- text-->
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-user"></i> My Profile</a>
                                <!-- text-->
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-wallet"></i> My Balance</a>
                                <!-- text-->
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-email"></i> Inbox</a>
                                <!-- text-->
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <!-- text-->
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-settings"></i> Account Setting</a>
                                <!-- text-->
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <!-- text-->
                                <a href="pages-login.html" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
                                <!-- text-->
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <!-- End User Profile -->
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <li class="nav-item right-side-toggle"> <a class="nav-link  waves-effect waves-light" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-settings"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- End Topbar header -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Left Sidebar - style you can find in sidebar.scss  -->
        <!-- ============================================================== --> 
        <aside class="left-sidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar scroll-->
            <div class="scroll-sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar navigation-->
                <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                    <ul id="sidebarnav">
                        <li class="user-pro"> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false"><img src="{% static 'core/assets/images/users/1.jpg' %}" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"><span class="hide-menu">Mark Jeckson</span></a>
                            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-wallet"></i> My Balance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-email"></i> Inbox</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-settings"></i> Account Setting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-small-cap">--- PERSONAL</li>
                        <li> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon-people"></i><span class="hide-menu">Estudiantes <span class="badge badge-pill badge-cyan ml-auto">2</span></span></a>
                            <ul aria-expanded="false" clas  s="collapse">
                                <li><a href="{% url 'estudiante:list' %}">Listar </a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon-wrench"></i><span class="hide-menu">Administrador <span class="badge badge-pill badge-cyan ml-auto">2</span></span></a>
                            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                                <li><a href="{% url 'semestre:list' %}">Semestres</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Generos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- End Sidebar navigation -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Sidebar scroll-->
        </aside>
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- End Left Sidebar - style you can find in sidebar.scss  -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Page wrapper  -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Container fluid  -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- Bread crumb and right sidebar toggle -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <div class="row page-titles">
                    <div class="col-md-5 align-self-center">
                        <h4 class="text-themecolor">{% block titlulo_pagina %}{% endblock %}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 align-self-center text-right">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                            {% block atras %}
                            {% endblock atras %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- End Bread crumb and right sidebar toggle -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- Start Page Content -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                {% block content %}{% endblock %} 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- End PAge Content -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- Right sidebar -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- .right-sidebar -->
                <div class="right-sidebar">
                    <div class="slimscrollright">
                        <div class="rpanel-title"> Configuración de panel <span><i class="ti-close right-side-toggle"></i></span> </div>
                        <div class="r-panel-body">
                            <ul id="themecolors" class="m-t-20">
                                <li><b>With Light sidebar</b></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-default" class="default-theme working">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-green" class="green-theme">2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-red" class="red-theme">3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-blue" class="blue-theme">4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-purple" class="purple-theme">5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-megna" class="megna-theme">6</a></li>
                                <li class="d-block m-t-30"><b>With Dark sidebar</b></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-default-dark" class="default-dark-theme ">7</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-green-dark" class="green-dark-theme">8</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-red-dark" class="red-dark-theme">9</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-blue-dark" class="blue-dark-theme">10</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-purple-dark" class="purple-dark-theme">11</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-megna-dark" class="megna-dark-theme ">12</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- End Right sidebar -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
            </div>
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- End Container fluid  -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
        </div>
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- End Page wrapper  -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- footer -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <footer class="footer">
            © 2018 Unidades Tecnológicas de Santander
        </footer>
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- End footer -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End Wrapper -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- All Jquery -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/assets/node_modules/vue/vue.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'core/assets/node_modules/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/assets/node_modules/popper/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'core/assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/dist/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/dist/js/waves.js' %}"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js' %}"></script>
    <!--stickey kit -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/assets/node_modules/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'core/assets/node_modules/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/dist/js/custom.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

**Base.html**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Principal{% endblock %}
{% block titlulo_pagina %}Principal{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Inicio Hola mundo</h1>
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
        }
    })
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

Esto es lo que me da como resultado, no me muestra nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya revisé los scripts y también me los está cargando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya usaste esto? python manage.py collectstatic, para recolectar nuevamente el contenido de tu carpeta 'static'. En settings.py podrías poner algo como esto: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
A mi me sirvió cuando tuve problemas para importar imágenes.

Comment: aqui deberia estar cerrado tu comentario.. <!--[if lt IE 9]>....asi: <!--[if lt IE 9] -->

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los deliminatores de Vue y de las plantillas de Django son iguales, deberías cambiarlos en la configuración de Vue.

```
{% block scripts %}
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

Comment: O sea que despues de agregar ese delimiters las variables de vues se escribirian asi?
`${ message }`

y si quiero que quede `{ message }` solamente deberia borrar el $?

Comment: YA lo probe y me funciono full, muchas gracias